# Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

Tags: node.js

I have created a service in node.js for basic crud operations. However when I start service it throws Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined] error. I am not able to figure out where the error is.

Here is my code.

Models:
agreement_master.js.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const agreementmaster = mongoose.Schema({


    ClientId:{type:Number},
    UserId:{type:Number},
    StartDate:{type:Date},


});

 var Agreement = module.exports = 
mongoose.model('Agreement',agreementmaster);


 module.exports.addmAgreement=function (data,callback){

    data.save(callback);

 }

 module.exports.getallmAgreement= function (data,callback){
    var query = {status:true};
    Agreement.find(query, callback);
 }
```

routes:
agreement_master.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    magreement = require('../controller/agreement_master');

router.post('/addmAgreement', magreement.addmAgreement);


module.exports = router;
```

Controller:
agreement_master.js

```
const Agreement= require('../models/agreement_master');


exports.addmAgreement = function (req, res){

    var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    var agreement = new Agreement(data); 
    agreement.ClientId = req.body.ClientId;
    agreement.UserId= req.body.UserId;
    agreement.StartDate=new Date();

    Agreement.addmAgreement(agreement, function (err, obj) {
       if (err) return res.json({err, status:'error'});
       if(obj){
           return res.json({
               message:'agreement added',

           });
       }
   });
};
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');

const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

 mongoose.connect('mongodb://local/local-host')

const app = express();
```

error comes at this part in the below line:

```
const agreement = require('./routes/agreement_master');
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(expressValidator());
app.use(cookieParser());
```

//Add Routes here

```
app.use('/agreement', agreement);
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3001));
    var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Server Started on port ' + app.get('port'));
    });




    module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 1):

user module.exports instead of exports.
exports doest export anything and will not be used by require();

```
module.exports.addmAgreement = function (req, res){

    var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    var agreement = new Agreement(data); 
    agreement.ClientId = req.body.ClientId;
    agreement.UserId= req.body.UserId;
    agreement.StartDate=new Date();

    Agreement.addmAgreement(agreement, function (err, obj) {
       if (err) return res.json({err, status:'error'});
       if(obj){
           return res.json({
               message:'agreement added',

           });
       }
   });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
router.post('/addmAgreement', function(req, res){
   magreement.addmAgreement
});
```

instead of

```
router.post('/addmAgreement', magreement.addmAgreement);
```

Comment: **try this** router.post('/addmAgreement', magreement().addmAgreement);

Comment: that means require function of route file is not getting the controller function make sure you exported and imported everything perfrctly

Comment: the routes are working properly and addmAgreement is the function which is been called in the controller file.

Comment: i am talking about this require **magreement = require('../controller/agreement_master');**  try to console.log(magreement)..see what it says